# Spring EasyMock getting null when calling the mocked method

Tags: java, spring, easymock

First time using EasyMock and Spring together.
I have the test class:

```
@RunWith(EasyMockRunner.class)
public class ProjectServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private ProjectRepository projectRepositoryMock;

    @TestSubject
    private ProjectService service new ProjectService();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        Project project = new Project("Project");

        EasyMock.expect(projectRepositoryMock.findOne(1)).andReturn(project);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void getProjectById() throws Exception {
      System.out.println(this.service.getProjectById(1);
    }
```

This is my project entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Project")
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String projectName;


    public Project(){

    }

    public Project(String projectName) {
        this.projectNaam = projectName;
    }
```

It also has the usual getters and setters.
My repository just extends the JpaRepository.
And this is my ProjectService class

```
@Service
public class ProjectService {

    @Autowired
    private ProjectRepository projectRepository;

    public ProjectService(){

    }

    public Project getProjectById(Integer id){
        return this.projectRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    public void saveProject(Project project){
        this.projectRepository.save(project);
    }

    public void deleteProject(Integer id){
        this.projectRepository.delete(id);
    }

    public List<Project> getAllProjects(){
        return this.projectRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Project findProjectById(Integer id){
        return this.projectRepository.findOne(id);
    }
}
```

My test failed so that's why I use system.out.println to figure out whats going on. It prints: null.

I don't understand this. @Mock and @TestSubject seems good, becauase I want to test the service and mock the repository.
Instead of

```
System.out.println(this.service.getProjectById(1);
```

I tried

```
System.out.println(this.projectRepositoryMock.findOne(1));
```

But this also returns null.

Comment: Did you also verify if the `@Before` is executed? Maybe it is the not the junit `@Before` and gets skipped.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the mock in replay mode. Try

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    Project project = new Project("Project");

    EasyMock.expect(projectRepositoryMock.findOne(1)).andReturn(project);
    EasyMock.replay(projectRepositoryMock);
}
```